# How to create a single date column from multiple date column with start date and end date?

Tags: mysql, sql, datediff, mysql-8.0

I have a table with this kind of data, with no overlapping dates:

| id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-12-20 | 2021-12-20 |
| 2 | 2021-12-15 | 2021-12-18 |
| 3 | 2021-12-10 | 2021-12-11 |

I want to have output as:

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-12-20 |
| 2 | 2021-12-18 |
| 2 | 2021-12-17 |
| 2 | 2021-12-16 |
| 2 | 2021-12-15 |
| 3 | 2021-12-11 |
| 3 | 2021-12-10 |

I tried creating table with generated dates between range `min(start_date) and max(end_date)` and using join with `WHERE date>=start_date and date<=end_date`.

Comment: What is MySQL version?

Comment: The MySQL version is 8.0.26

Comment: Use recursive CTE.

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursive CTE in order to generate rows along with joining to your table (`t`) such as

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE cte
AS
(
SELECT 1 i
UNION ALL
SELECT i + 1 i
  FROM cte
 WHERE i + 1 <= ( SELECT DATEDIFF(MAX(end_date),MIN(start_date))+1 FROM t )  
), dmin AS
(
 SELECT MIN(start_date) AS min_date FROM t
)
SELECT id, DATE_ADD(t2.min_date, INTERVAL i-1 DAY) AS date
  FROM cte
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM t JOIN dmin ) AS t2
    ON DATE_ADD(t2.min_date, INTERVAL i-1 DAY) >= start_date 
   AND DATE_ADD(t2.min_date, INTERVAL i-1 DAY) <= end_date
 WHERE start_date IS NOT NULL 
 ORDER BY id, date DESC
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7ec61258f14e6e1833e5c654c8d9ad9b)</kbd>